# Changing the location of a child user control dynamically

Tags: .net, wpf

I have created an user control which have another user control as child inside it. I have tried moving  the child user control bu issuing the following statement

`this.versionDisplay.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,10.0);`

But VS2010 is showing an error as follows

> Error 23  'MainApp.MainGui.MainControls.MainTitleControl' does not
>   contain a definition for 'versionDisplay' and no extension method
>   'versionDisplay' accepting a first argument of type
>   'MainApp.MainGui.MainControls.MainTitleControl' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am sure that name of the child control is versionDisplay.

Code for MainTitleControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Main.MainGui.MainControls.MainTitleControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:wcontrols="clr-namespace:WEPA.MainGui.MainControls"
     Height="80" Width="395" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" >

     <Grid Background="Transparent"  >
         <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="635" Height="120" Source="/MainApplication;component/images/UnCategorized/Wireless.png" Margin="12,0,0,0" / >
         <wcontrols:supportInfoControl Name="versionDisplay" Height="20" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="70" Margin="200,95,-114,-35" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please advice.

Comment: You should perhaps post the relevant XAML of `MainTitleControl`.

Comment: Have you tried setting x:Name="versionDisplay" instead? Why can't it find your control in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your nested UserControl (wcontrols:supportInfoControl) appears to be contained in a Grid, so even if you were setting the Canvas.Top property correctly as such:

```
Canvas.SetTop(this.versionDisplay, 10.0);
```

Then it still would have no effect. I would try this:

```
this.versionDisplay.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0.0, 10.0);
```

You don't specify what effect you want this relocation to have on the sibling and parent elements, so for that reason I suggested the RenderTransform. If you want different overall behavior, you will need to be more specific.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't his error suggest it can't find the variable for the control at all?

Comment: Perhaps, but given the code snippet `this.versionDisplay.SetValue()`, wouldn't it throw a compiler error if that were the case?

Comment: My mistake, Alan...I see the designer error. I should have read better.